# Allowing user inputs that have spaces (" ")

Tags: google-maps, jsf, oracle-adf

I am creating a program that takes an address that the user inputs, and using GeoCoder, places that address on a map.  This is done through oracle adf thematic map and java for the backing bean.  The issue I'm getting is that the input works, but only if there are no spaces in the user's input. When an input is entered that DOES have a space, I get this error:

```
<oracle.adf.view> <PartialResponseUtils> <handleError> <ADF_FACES-60096:Server Exception during PPR, #1> 
javax.el.ELException: .../map.jsf @76,86 pointX="#{row.lattitude}": java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Since GeoCoder doesn't care about spaces, I'm guessing the error is in the map code? Here's the code for the map jsf page:

```
<af:form id="f1">
    <af:panelStretchLayout topHeight="50px" id="psl1">
        <f:facet name="top">
            <af:panelHeader text="Regional Map" id="ph1">
                <f:facet name="context"/>
                <f:facet name="menuBar"/>
                <f:facet name="toolbar"/>
                <f:facet name="legend"/>
                <f:facet name="info"/>
            </af:panelHeader>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="center">
            <af:panelSplitter id="ps1" splitterPosition="289">
                <f:facet name="first">
                    <af:decorativeBox id="db1">
                        <f:facet name="center">
                            <af:panelGroupLayout layout="scroll" id="pgl1">
                                <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1">
                                    <f:facet name="footer">
                                        <af:commandButton text="Add Location" id="cb1" partialSubmit="true"
                                                          actionListener="#{locationsCollector.addCurrentLocation}"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <af:inputText label="Label" id="it1" autoSubmit="true"
                                                  value="#{currentLocation.label}"/>
                                    <af:inputText label="Description" id="it1a" autoSubmit="true"
                                                  value="#{currentLocation.description}"/>
                                    <af:inputText label="Location (NO SPACES)" id="it2" autoSubmit="true"
                                                  value="#{currentLocation.location}"/>
                                </af:panelFormLayout>
                                <af:spacer id="spac1" height="40"/>
                                <af:table value="#{locationsCollector.locations}" var="row"
                                          rowBandingInterval="0" id="t1" partialTriggers="::cb1">
                                    <af:column sortable="false" headerText="Label" align="start" id="c1">
                                        <af:outputText value="#{row.label}" id="ot1"
                                                       shortDesc="#{row.description}"/>
                                    </af:column>
                                    <af:column sortable="false" headerText="Description" align="start" id="c2">
                                        <af:outputText value="#{row.description}" id="ot2"/>
                                    </af:column>
                                    <!--<af:column sortable="false" headerText="Country" align="start" id="c3">
                                        <af:outputText value="#{row.country}" id="ot3"/>
                                    </af:column>-->
                                </af:table>
                            </af:panelGroupLayout>
                        </f:facet>
                        <!--<f:facet name="top">
                            <af:panelHeader text="Enter location details" id="ph2">
                                <f:facet name="context"/>
                                <f:facet name="menuBar"/>
                                <f:facet name="toolbar"/>
                                <f:facet name="legend"/>
                                <f:facet name="info"/>
                            </af:panelHeader>
                        </f:facet>-->
                    </af:decorativeBox>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="second">
                    <dvt:thematicMap basemap="usa" id="tm1" partialTriggers="::cb1" summary="map">
                        <dvt:areaLayer layer="states" id="al1" rendered="true">
                            <dvt:pointDataLayer id="pdl1c" value="#{locationsCollector.locations}" var="row">
                                <dvt:pointLocation id="pl1c" type="pointXY" pointX="#{row.lattitude}"
                                                   pointY="#{row.longitude}">
                                    <dvt:marker id="m1c" labelDisplay="on" value="#{row.label}"
                                                labelPosition="top"
                                                shortDesc="#{row.description} #{row.location} "/>
                                </dvt:pointLocation>
                            </dvt:pointDataLayer>
                        </dvt:areaLayer>
                    </dvt:thematicMap>
                </f:facet>
            </af:panelSplitter>
            <!-- id="af_one_column_header_stretched"  -->
        </f:facet>
    </af:panelStretchLayout>
</af:form>
```

And here is the bean for getting the latitude and longitude from Geocoder to add to the map's point detail:

```
public class Location {

    private String location;
    private String country;
    private String label;
    private String description;
    private float[] coordinates;

    private static float[] getCoordinatesForLocation(String location) {
        URL geoCodeUrl;

        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + location
                + "&oe=utf8&sensor=false";
        try {
            geoCodeUrl
                    = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " url=" + url);
            return null;
        }
        BufferedReader in;
        String coord = null;
        try {

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(geoCodeUrl.openStream()));
            char[] buf = new char[8000];

            in.read(buf);
            coord = new StringBuilder().append(buf).toString();

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " IO Exception ");
            return null;
        }

        if (coord != null) {
            float[] coordinates;
            try {
                // find first occurrence of lat
                int posLAT = coord.indexOf("\"lat\"");
                String latString = coord.substring(posLAT, posLAT + 21);

                String lat = latString.split(":")[1].replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll(",", "");
                // find first occurrence of lng
                int posLNG = coord.indexOf("\"lng\"");
                String lngString = coord.substring(posLNG, posLNG + 21);
                String lng = lngString.split(":")[1].replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll(",", "");

                coordinates
                        = new float[]{Float.parseFloat(lat), Float.parseFloat(lng)};
                return coordinates;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Coordinates stank " + coord);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Failed to create proper coordinates; sorry!");
        return null;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(float[] coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public float[] getCoordinates() {
        if (coordinates == null) {
            coordinates = getCoordinatesForLocation(location);
        }
        return coordinates;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return getCoordinates()[0];
    }

    public float getLattitude() {
        return getCoordinates()[1];
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

All I'm looking for is the ability for the program to accept an address with spaces so the program is more user friendly.  Thanks for looking this over!

Comment: Can you post your entire stack trace please?

Comment: how about replace " " into "+"..?